# What is the equivalent of psycopg curs.mogrify on mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, psycopg

What would be the equivalent of psycopg's `cur.mogrify` on mysql?

From: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html

> mogrify(operation[, parameters])
>   Return a query string after arguments binding. The string returned is exactly the one that would be sent to the database running the execute() method or similar.
>
> >cur.mogrify("INSERT INTO test (num, data) VALUES (%s, %s)", (42, 'bar'))
>   >"INSERT INTO test (num, data) VALUES (42, E'bar')"
>
> > DB API extension The mogrify() method is a Psycopg extension to the DB API 2.0.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have anything built in that returns a query string like this. If you want to perform a query with variables substituted in, you use `PREPARE` and EXECUTE:

```
PREPARE stmt AS "INSERT INTO test(num, data) VALUES (?, ?)";
EXECUTE stmt USING 42, 'bar';
```

Answer (score 4):

As per [this](https://www.compose.com/articles/formatted-sql-in-python-with-psycopgs-mogrify/) example, you can see the results of the "mogrify" after the statement has been executed.

```
import MySQLdb

conn = MySQLdb.connect()
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT %s, %s', ('bar', 1))
print cursor._executed
```

Which will print

```
SELECT 'bar', 1
```

Moreover, you don't need to use mogrify before execution

```
query = cursor.mogrify('SELECT %s, %s', ('bar', 1))
cursor.execute(query)
```

You can simply do the following

```
cursor.execute('SELECT %s, %s', ('bar', 1))
```

This will work across [all DBs that use the Python DB API](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DatabaseInterfaces)